# Fetch Metadata from URL

Tags: android, url, metadata

I have an application in which I am fetching the metadata from URL with this API:
https://api.urlmeta.org/?url=www.example.com

It was working fine few days ago but now, it get closed. Now, When I enter any url it gives error: "There's nothing here, yet."

I am searching any alternatives to this, but nothing helps.
Please provide some url or any idea how to achieve the functionality.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to fetch the metadata from url like image, it's title and description etc.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using JSOUP library in android.

Add This is your app level `build.gradle` file

`implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.1'`

Get URL metadata using following function.

```
public void printUrlMatadata(String url){
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").get();
        String keywords = doc.select("meta[name=keywords]").first().attr("content");
        System.out.println("Meta keyword : " + keywords);
        String description = doc.select("meta[name=description]").get(0).attr("content");
        System.out.println("Meta description : " + description);
    }
```